# how to send binary packet using GCDAsyncSocket

Tags: iphone, gcdasyncsocket

I have created connection with a hard ware device , using CGDAsyncSocket , but now next step is to send binary data to that device , so i am very much confused how to construct that packet whose description is  given below

```
field=packet_id
byte=1
value=0X01
```

Please help I am weired on this point

Answer (score 0):

usually using CGDAsyncSocket is pretty simple:

```
NSData *chunkSize = you data, + (id)dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length can be used to setup u own packet.

[asyncSocket writeData:chunkSize withTimeout:TIMEOUT_WRITE_HEAD tag:HTTP_CHUNKED_RESPONSE_HEADER];
```

here is instruction to construct bytes:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/BinaryData/Tasks/WorkingMutableData.html

example:
const unsigned char newBytes[4] = { 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08 };

Comment: you are not getting , my problem is how to construct the packet containing above data format